# Enabling support for SHA256 in JDK 1.7.0 U221

Tags: java, ssl, java-7, sha256

Apparently, the followings ciphers are not supported in JDK 1.7.0 U221

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

Is there a way to add support for these?

Comment: Maybe try using some provider like BouncyCastle.

Comment: How did you conclude so ? The [Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/javase7supportreleasenotes-1601161.html#R170_191) says it's supported since 7u191

Comment: Read about java cryptographic extension maybe it is a part of that.

Comment: @EugèneAdel+ the first two are reported added at 7u191 (presumably backported from 8); the latter two were already there back to 7u0, although only when TLSv1.2 is used which was not default for client until 7u131.  Saqib: are you trying to use those names in Java? Those are the OpenSSL names, not the RFC names which Java uses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Java Cryptographic Extension

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: This is required for AES 256, not AES 128 (see [JSSE Reference Guide 7 Footnote 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#footnote-two)

Comment: @EugèneAdell: and per the release notes above, not even for AES256 (or other symmetric 256) since 7u171 in Jan 2018, roughly the same time it was also effectively removed for 8 (8u151 and 8u161) and 9.0.0